# str_replace double quote from word

Tags: php, str-replace, double-quotes

I have json data as a string that is being passed to javascript. Before the string is passed though, I am doing a search in php for all double quotes and replacing them. This is working fine but some of the json strings have (what looks like) an MS Word style double quote, possibly italicized. So my `<?php $t = str_replace("”", "", $t); ?>` method call is not escaping the special double quotes.

Do I need to find the charcode and escape that? I tried splicing the quote out of the string and then pasting it into the php method but it still won't recognize the character as a different double quote.

Let me see if I can paste the quote in here -- `< “ >` and `< ” >`

thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to replace them?

Comment: are these double quotes part of the JSON formatting or are they data themselves?

Comment: part of the user's input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
function mb_str_replace($needle, $replacement, $haystack) {
   return implode($replacement, mb_split($needle, $haystack));
}
$t = "as“da”sd";
$t = mb_str_replace("”", "", $t); 
$t = mb_str_replace("“", "", $t); 
#and all the other weird quotes :)
echo $t;
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

i would suggest to use preg_replace instead

```
$t = "as“da”sd";
$t = preg_replace("/[”“]/u","",$t); #just create a character class
echo $t;
```

this might be useful as well:
http://axonflux.com/handy-regexes-for-smart-quotes

Comment: thanks for the detail @jackdoe what does the /u represent... it is giving me `Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 0` error.

Comment: @TimJoyce btw, dont forget to save your php in UTF-8 format, otherwise you will have to input character codes for the specific quotes, because even if they look OK at the editor after the save they might get butchered, and then even the first str_replace will work, but i always tend to be specific when working with unicode, so i am sure that the functions i am using know that it is unicode

Comment: lifesaver... thank you, used the preg_replace with and added the header `<?php header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' ); ?>` works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it myself , so only thing i could come up with that you have to use UTF-8 encoding.

```
<?php
    header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $str = "“ > and < ”\"";
    $replaceArr =  array("“", "”", "\"");
    $replaced = str_replace($replaceArr,"",$str);
    echo $replaced;
?>
```

Looks clean for me when i try it.